# The simplest video streaming?

Tags: python, video, video-streaming

I have a camera that is taking pictures one by one (about 10 pictures per second) and sending them to PC. I need to show this incoming sequence of images as a live video in PC.

Is it enough just to use some Python GUI framework, create a control that will hold a single image and just change the image in the control very fast?

Or would that be just lame? Should I use some sort of video streaming library? If yes, what do you recommend?

Comment: I think that changing the picture very rapidly would be terribly inefficient... It would be best to use a library to take those pictures and make a stream, yes.

Comment: @Rafe Kettler. What library do you recommend? I'm using python to send and receive images.

Comment: @RichardKnop I'm not sure *what* video library you might use, just certain that whatever you're doing now probably won't work. S. Lott's answer is correct about what you need to do, just not how to do it. Sadly, I can't help you--my best suggestion would be that you can do some of those tasks (compression, buffering, etc.) from the command line using `popen`

Comment: @Rafe Kettler Thanks for suggestions but I am already using UDP socket to transfer images, I think that should be ok. Basically I want to do all the encoding of images and creating a stream out of them on the server (PC). My client is just a small humanoid robot with IP camera and it does not have CPU power and RAM to do anything complex (it has 500Mhz CPU and 256MB RAM). So long story short I have a program running on the PC which is receiving images from the robot and I just need to show them as a real time video. I will probably ask this as a separate question later to get detailed answers.

Comment: @RichardKnop 500mhz CPU and 256MB of RAM? That's a lot, hombre. I remember my first computer had about that.

Comment: @Rafe Kettler But there is losts of other stuff running on the robot already (modules for motion, vision, sonar, speech, hearing etc) so it's not like I have all 500Mhz and 256MB RAM free to do something complex like video encoding. Check my new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4035365/live-video-stream-on-server-pc-from-images-sent-by-robot-through-udp

Comment: @RichardKnop yeah, 500mhz probably isn't enough, I'm just in shock that microprocessors have come that far...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Or would that be just lame?

No.  It wouldn't work at all.

There's a trick to getting video to work.  Apple's QuickTime implements that trick.  So does a bunch of Microsoft product.  Plus some open source video playback tools.

There are several closely-related tricks, all of which are a huge pain in the neck.

1. Compression.  Full-sized video is Huge.  Do the math 640x480x24-bit color at 30 frames per second.  It adds up quickly.  Without compression, you can't read it in fast enough.
2. Buffering and Timing.  Sometimes the data rates and frame rates don't align well.  You need a buffer of ready-to-display frames and you need a deadly accurate clock to get them do display at exactly the right intervals.

Making a sequence of JPEG images into a movie is what iPhoto and iMovie are for.

Usually, what we do is create the video file from the image and play the video file through a standard video player.  Making a QuickTime movie or Flash movie from images isn't that hard.  There are a lot of tools to help make movies from images.  Almost any photo management solution can create a slide show and save it as a movie in some standard format.

Indeed, I think that Graphic Converter can do this.

Comment: I need the video to be a live stream (i.e. I see on the PC what camera sees right now). So I guess I will need to use some video streaming library for that.

Comment: "I have a flow of JPEG images".  "I need the video to be a live stream".  I can't follow your requirements.  They appear contradictory.  At the very least they're incomplete.  Please **update** the question to have **all** the relevant information.

Comment: I don't know how to explain it better. The camera is taking pictures one by one and sending them to a PC. I need to show a live video from these images (camera takes about 10 images per second). I will update my question.

Comment: @Richard Knop: "I don't know how to explain it better." That's not the issue.  Until your latest update, you didn't explain it at all.  We can't read minds.  So without **details**, we can only guess.  And in this case, more details would be helpful, since what you're asking for isn't proper video (30 fps), yet you want it in "real" time.  You have a seriously complex problem and you need to provide details.

Comment: I have tried to explain everything in much more detail in my new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4035365/live-video-stream-on-server-pc-from-images-sent-by-robot-through-udp