# Creating a video stream server + receiver

Tags: video-streaming, client-server

I'll generate images in realtime on one computer. I want to stream this and have a few clients (on LAN, or other highspeed internet) read this stream.

I want to write code for this (not use some tools). Any pointers where I should look for information? Or any terms that I should search for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I am not familiar with the topic I have found the following pages that may help you:

- A Java [course work](http://www.cs.umbc.edu/~pmundur/courses/CMSC691C/lab5-kurose-ross.html) material with sources.
- A similar, python-related [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4035365/live-video-stream-on-server-pc-from-images-sent-by-robot-through-udp) where the source is a set of jpegs.
- An OpenCV [tutorial](http://nashruddin.com/Streaming_OpenCV_Videos_Over_the_Network) with sources. I know you are good at it. :)